# Two group structures on the cotangent bundle of a Lie group. Are they related?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group, and consider its cotangent bundle $T^*G$. There are two ways of viewing this space.

1. Using left translation, we can trivialize $T^*G\cong G\times{\frak g}^*$. (Where ${\frak g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$.) Moreover, $G$ acts on ${\frak g}^*$ via the coadjoint action, so we can consider the semi-direct product
   $$G\ltimes_{{\rm Ad}} {\frak g}^*.$$
   This gives a Lie group structure on $T^*G$.
2. On the other hand, there is a diffeomorphism $T^*G\cong G_{\Bbb C}$, where $G_{\Bbb C}$ is the complexification of $G$. (It comes from the map $G\times{\frak g}\to G_{\Bbb C},(g,X)\mapsto ge^{iX}$.) This gives a second Lie group structure on $T^*G$.

> Does these two group structures have any interesting relation?

I don't have a counterexample, but I don't suspect the group structures to be the same. However can we still say something about their relation? In particular:

> - Can we construct the group structure of $G_{\Bbb C}$ in a natural way from the one on $G\ltimes_{{\rm Ad}} {\frak g}^*$?
> - Is there an interesting subset of $T^*G$ on which they coincide?

Comment: They're certainly not the same; you can compare their Lie algebras, and usually the second will be semisimple but the first won't.

Comment: Why is that map a diffeomorphic to the complexification?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez You can find a proof in, for example, Bump - Lie groups, or Knapp - Lie groups beyond an introduction. It is sometimes refer to as the *polar decomposition*.